# save a text from text file through rails console

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, creation, rails-console

like in title - I want to save a content of a text file in database (and couple other things) through rails console - how to do it?

I'm entering rails console by:
`rails c`
and then I should do

```
`MyItem.create! body: content_from_my_text_file, field1: '123', field2: 'abc'
```

but how force rails console to read from file and write the content to the database? Is there any simple solution? Please help!

Comment: `content_from_my_text_file = File.read('/path/to/file')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need rails to read a file. You could get all the data of a file in a string with `IO.read(path)`.

You should read more about it in:

- http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html
- http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html